# Azure B2C Custom Policy web app call Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I've got a web application that I authenticate to Azure B2C with Custom Policy. I'd like to call a web api that receives the token I just received from authenticating.

Here is my Web App.

```
         services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
         .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(options =>
         {
             Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
         })
         .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { Configuration["ApiScope"] })
         .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

        services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options => {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                            .Build();
        }).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

And here is my Web API:

```
             services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
             .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
             {
                 Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);

                 options.TokenValidationParameters.NameClaimType = "name";
             },
             options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options); });
```

Sample controller, that requires a token to call web api.

```
[AuthorizeForScopes()]
public class PetsController : Controller
```

`[AuthorizeForScopes()]` is causing a redirect to the generic Azure AD login page, rather than to the custom policy flow. Is this something that I can configure?

I can login and get a token, but it it should be redirecting me to the custom policy flow instead of the generic Azure AD login.

Comment: You want to sign up for Azure AD and return the token and custom policy. And then based on that, call your API? Did I understand correctly? Will you have multiple API services and then redirect to a specific service based on tokens and custom policies or will you always have you have only that one API service? Can you send a picture of your architecture (you can draw in paint)?

Comment: @MilošPantelinac  Login with Custom Policy -> Web App -> Web API.  Basically we login to a MVC app, the MVC app calls web API for data. Issue is the web api is making me authenticate again, and I'm not sure why since I already have a token from the custom policy.

Comment: It would seem the issue is coming from the authentication in the app has not expired, but their is nothing in the token cache. Is there anyway for me to fix this? Not sure why I'm still authenticated, but the token cache is empty.;

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below is your case to workaound.

Please make sure you have added add Azure B2C settings including policy in  “appsettings.json” file and see if you have to add to do list scopes too under that.

```
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://contoso.b2clogin.com",
    "Domain": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "<web-api-app-application-id>",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/<your-sign-up-in-policy>",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "<your-sign-up-in-policy>"
  },
  // More settings here
}
```

assuming you have `Services.addControllers();` in start up configure services
Then, immediately after the app.UseRouting();

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

When controller is decorated with say for example  [RequiredScope("User.read")]. The RequiredScopeAttribute verifies that the web API is called with the right scopes, ex: User.read.

Try with `[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new string[] { "User.Read" })]` (if your scope for api permission is different please change that) but i have seen  some cases where that authorizeforscopes attriubte not  working in case of API.

Ex:

```
[AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { })]
[Authorize(Policy = )]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> Get()
{
```

So try like below with the scopes you have. Before that please make sure you have exposed api in app portal, given api permission and granted admin consent for them.Give that scope permission in the requiredScope.Also see [Verify scopes and app roles protected web API - Microsoft identity platform | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles?tabs=aspnetcore#verify-app-roles-in-apis-called-by-daemon-apps)

```
[Authorize]
[RequiredScope("User.read")]
```

Please check the technical profile if it includes scopes and endpoints to redirect and check UserRedirectionPolicyUri in key item is set.
For in detail info on modifications need to be done please see  [Azure-Sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi#step-5-configure-your-visual-studio-project-with-your-azure-ad-b2c-app-registrations).

If the issue is not with above configuration see if multiple apis are listed as mentioned in comment else you may feel free to provide some more configurations or raise a support ticket.

Other References :

1. [b2c/configure-authentication-sample-web-app-with-api | Microsoft
   docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-web-app-with-api?tabs=visual-studio)
2. [b2c/enable-authentication-web-api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/enable-authentication-web-api?tabs=csharpclient#prerequisites)

Comment: I have everything you stated here. The issue is that the web api is making me authenticate again, even though I already have a token and what not from the custom policy.

Comment: It would seem the issue is coming from the authentication in the app has not expired, but their is nothing in the token cache. Is there anyway for me to fix this? Not sure why I'm still authenticated, but the token cache is empty.;